# mysql increment value at current row and reset for each group

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a default contract number for a client and I try to add parts of each contract. In this case I use `Number` column as combined `contract id` with the consecutive number of rows for each client.

this is the query

```
select '0' as Id, CONCAT(ea.Id, '-', count(loc.Id)) as Number, loc.* 
from EnergyAgreement ea 
left join (
    select 1545 as Id, 301005 as custId UNION ALL
    select 2454 as Id, 301005 as custId UNION ALL
    select 3654 as Id, 301005 as custId UNION ALL
    select 1546 as Id, 301008 as custId UNION ALL
    select 2454 as Id, 301008 as custId             
) as loc ON loc.custId = ea.CustomerId 
where ea.CustomerId IN (301005, 301008)
group by loc.Id, loc.custId  
order by Number ASC`
```

and here is the result which is wrong (see column `Number`)

```
"Id" "Number" "Id"   "custId"
"0"  "77-1"   "1545" "301005"
"0"  "77-1"   "2454" "301005"
"0"  "77-1"   "3654" "301005"
"0"  "81-1"   "2454" "301008"
"0"  "81-1"   "1546" "301008"
```

how to build the query to consecutive increment the `Number` column until next `customer ID` occurrence, so I can obtain a correct set result as below?:

```
"Id" "Number" "Id"   "custId"
"0"  "77-1"   "1545" "301005"
"0"  "77-2"   "2454" "301005"
"0"  "77-3"   "3654" "301005"
"0"  "81-1"   "2454" "301008"
"0"  "81-2"   "1546" "301008"
```

Comment: why couldnt you use auto increment to increment the values ??

Comment: how? and that value should be reset to each client Id ..

Answer (score 1):

Just add the values you want in the `loc` subquery:

```
select '0' as Id, CONCAT(ea.Id, '-', loc.n) as Number, loc.id, loc.custId
from EnergyAgreement ea left join
     (select 1545 as Id, 301005 as custId, 1 as n UNION ALL
      select 2454 as Id, 301005 as custId, 2 UNION ALL
      select 3654 as Id, 301005 as custId, 3 UNION ALL
      select 1546 as Id, 301008 as custId, 1 UNION ALL
      select 2454 as Id, 301008 as custId, 2          
     ) loc
     on loc.custId = ea.CustomerId 
where ea.CustomerId IN (301005, 301008)
group by loc.Id, loc.custId, loc.n 
order by Number ASC`
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a solution like [this solution at `Method 2`](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/03/09/mysql-reset-row-number-for-each-group-partition-by-row-number/):

```
select '0' as Id, CONCAT(@Id:=ea.Id, '-', @row_number:=CASE WHEN @Id=loc.Id THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END) as Number, loc.* 
from EnergyAgreement ea 
left join (
    select 1545 as Id, 301005 as custId UNION ALL
    select 2454 as Id, 301005 as custId UNION ALL
    select 3654 as Id, 301005 as custId UNION ALL
    select 1546 as Id, 301008 as custId UNION ALL
    select 2454 as Id, 301008 as custId             
) as loc ON loc.custId = ea.CustomerId, (SELECT @row_number:=0,@Id:='') AS t
where ea.CustomerId IN (301005, 301008)
group by loc.Id, loc.custId  
order by Number ASC`
```

I can't test it right now, But I think it should work ;).